# Adding a compiler to run a java code and show the output

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-construction

I am making an android app which can run **c, c++ and java** programs. The app stores the respective files in a folder and is made to execute with the following code. Whenever I click on compile button it shows an IO Exception saying "**error=13 permission denied**".

```
 try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + "/PocketIDE/JavaPrograms/"+ filename);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output2.append(line).append("\n");
                    p.waitFor();
                }
                String response = output2.toString();
                output.setText(response);
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                output.setText(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Is the above method the correct way to execute the program? or do I need to change the code?

Comment: In order to read files from the device, you need to request the correct permissions. Google something like "android request file permission" for more details.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have already requested the permission to modify, read and write the external storage in the manifest...do I need to include any other permission too?

Comment: Let's step back for a moment. What line causes the error? I assume the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method, right? Read and write permissions don't let you execute anything. And even if it did, exucuting arbitary code with the same runtime instance that runs your app seems dangerous. You should fork a new process to run the program so it can run in its own sandbox and doesn't interfere with your app when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>             p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + "/PocketIDE/JavaPrograms/"+ filename);
> ```

You shouldn't run arbitrary Java code with the runtime that controls the execution of your app. This opens a massive security flaw, so Android disallows it. Instead, you should find a way to execute the Java code in its own environment and runtime.

Comment: Okay thanks I will look for another way to execute the code. The answer was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The statement in your code can be used to execute other programs, but it is not necessarily a good idea.

The `exec` method internally [forks](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java;l=125;bpv=1;bpt=1) the application`s process and creates a new one, which immediately executes the system command you give it.

From the path in your code I assume that you try to execute a binary executable, which is not allowed anymore by Android since API level 28:

> Untrusted apps that target Android 10 cannot invoke exec() on files within the app's home directory. This execution of files from the writable app home directory is a W^X violation. Apps should load only the binary code that's embedded within an app's APK file.

The only possible solution is to reduce the API level to 28 or include the binary in the APK file during packaging.

Comment: When you think about it the "possible solution" is compromising security.  Not a solution at all really.

Comment: Regarding my first solution, you are right. I only included it because I think that OP used code from some blog and is wondering why it is not working (only works with older API levels).  Applications using the "possible solution" cannot be distributed over the Play Store anymore and should not be distributed in any other way. Nonetheless, I think for educational and personal purposes only it is a valid solution if it removes the error from the question.